# Can I break down a weapon into mods (not junk)?

Tags: fallout-4

Let's say I have 10mm pistol. **Can I break it down so I'm left with no pistol, and a [barrel, magazine, sight, grip] etc?**

I ask because I'm finding myself in the early game with mods across 3-4 pistols that I'd like to combine into one, but I lack the extra junk/spare mods to swap things around.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's not possible to do this without any component cost. Scrapping a weapon destroys its mods.

But it shouldn't take long to find a few spare weapons, break them down, and make enough components for a swap at a relatively low component cost. If you can manage to afford the Level 1 Scrapper perk this gets even easier.

It sounds like you might know how to do this already, but in case it helps you or others—let's say you have a Powerful Receiver mod on pistol A, and you want to move it to pistol B.

1. At the weapons workbench, select Pistol A, select the Standard Receiver mod, then choose Build. Though this isn't free, it's really pretty component-cheap.
2. Look in your inventory to confirm. You should see a Powerful Receiver mod in the Mods inventory tab. This mod is now available to apply to other pistols.
3. At the crafting bench, choose Pistol B and navigate to the Powerful Receiver mod. Since you already have one, instead of Build you'll see an option to Attach.

Comment: This is what I'm doing right now. I'm sure over time it will be more of a non-issue as I accumulate spare mods, but it's annoying right now producing 'burner' mods, especially when adhesives seems to be the most precious being used in just about _everything_. Maybe a disassemble option will become available in a later patch.

Comment: John later on in towns you can buy packs of components like adhesives.  As for later patches I'd count on mods instead :)

Comment: @John I hear you, adhesive is hard early on. Besides keeping your eyes open for duct tape and wonderglue, if you're willing to farm you can create the richest source of adhesive--vegetable paste: http://www.gamezone.com/originals/fallout-4-guide-a-renewable-way-to-create-your-own-adhesive-jxc8

Comment: Or [this question regarding FO4 and adhesives](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/243060/how-can-i-get-more-adhesive)

Comment: @John When you upgrade weapons, keep the old standard mod in your workshop for later. I try not to sell any mods or scrap them on weapons unless I have another extra mod for that slot for that weapon.

Comment: Are there any mods that allow you to properly disasssemble a weapon into its mods?

Answer (score 2):

You cant completely disassemble a weapon.  You must be able to have enough mats to replace the mod with the base option at a minimum.

Answer (score 1):

***Both of these solutions require modding your game.***
There is unfortunately no **good** solution achieveable without mods.

---

#### 1st - [Free Weapon Downgrades](https://www.nexusmods.com/fallout4/mods/2073)

Gets around the problem by simply making the lowest-tier / "default" mod for that slot free to craft. Install the "no profit" version to make the standard mod crates (unattached loose items) have zero market value, to preserve balance.

##### Optional extra - [No Standard Mod Crates](https://www.nexusmods.com/fallout4/mods/5544/?tab=files)

For convenience with Free Downgrades; stops the now-worthless standard mod crates from being created in your inventory when replaced.

---

#### 2nd - [Craft and Dismantle Weapons](https://www.nexusmods.com/fallout4/mods/24318)

This adds a new "weapon blueprint" item and allows weapons to be in a non-functioning state if they're missing a receiver. Seems to introduce a few more finicky items & mechanics than it needs to (it includes a portable weapon mod *switching*, but not *crafting*, workstation to swap mods in the field), but makes a little more in-world sense and is more potentially more robust to other weapon mods than Free Downgrades.