# How can I get more adhesive?

Tags: fallout-4

I've found that my modding sprees almost always end when I run out of adhesive.

I keep adhesive marked as a needed component all the time, and grab every piece of marked junk I see. I also check every vendor for duct tape and the like.

Is there a more reliable way to get adhesive in the quantities I require without cheating?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

There are a few other ways of getting adhesive.

At the cooking station, you can make something called Vegetable Starch out of:

- Corn
- Mutfruit
- Purified Water
- Tato

This is equivalent to 5 units adhesive.

The best part about this is that the plants are easy to grow and harvest (just use the first few harvests to plant more of them instead of using them up).  As for purified water, you can make that out of 3 dirty waters.  Also, if you construct a water purifier at your settlement, you will occasionally get purified water deposited into your stash.

Also in the major towns like Diamond City as well as on the roving caravns, the vendors occasionally carry an item called Shipment of Adhesive.  This will give you a large quantity of adhesive when bought.

Comment: That starch looks like the way to go. I noticed the adhesive shipments, but they're super expensive.

Comment: @DCShannon yes they are :(  Especially since I never bothered to get the trading perks yet.  I've been making a lot of vegetable starch myself.

Comment: I can't find mutfruit for the life of me. I have 'Wild Mutfruit', but it can't be planted. Anyone idea where to find some?

Comment: JClaspill try grey garden.  Also settlers might randomly have one in their inventory.

Comment: Interestingly, I just ran across this same tip on another site during random browsing earlier. Best thing to do, it seems, is to grab starter plants from Greygarden and build a water purifier early on in the game. Then just remember to harvest regularly.

Comment: @Iszi you done even have to harvest regularly.  Any unused resources produced goes straight into your workshop stash

Comment: About purified water: I was a bit surprised to be able to build a purifier in Sanctuary just from the resources I'd collected up to the Workstation tutorial missions, plus scrapping Ruined Houses and other local junk.

Answer (score 2):

Look for red tool boxes, they have wonder glue or duct tape which both contain adhesive

Answer (score 2):

z' has [provided the solution](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/243062/108003), in Vegetable Starch.

After having played through the first part of the game six or seven times, here are some tips on getting your Vegetable Starch production going.

You need three things for Vegetable Starch:

- At least one Corn, Tato, and Mutfruit
- Settlers to farm the crops
- Purified Water

**Seeds**

You may happen across the seeds randomly as loot or being sold by a vendor. I've bought all three of those things from Trudy at the Drumlin Diner, but not all three at once in the same playthrough. I've found corn in a container as early as the Workhouse in Concord.

If you don't happen across the seeds, there are locations where you can always find them. Abernathy Farm has plenty of Tatos, but no Corn or Mutfruit. If you follow the usual path from Vault 111 to Diamond City, the first place you'll see all the crops you need is [Graygarden](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Graygarden). You can make a beeline here from Vault 111 with barely a combat encounter, if you want to get things jump started.

At Graygarden, you'll see many Mutfruit outside. Inside, you'll find Corn, Tatos, and Mutfruit planters. These refresh on their own even before you gain Graygarden's allegiance.

**Settlers**

I suggest setting up a farm in Sanctuary.

You can put up a recruitment beacon before meeting Preston, if you like. You can find most or all of the components in Sanctuary and Vault 111, the most difficult being the Crystals.

Or, you can [rescue Preston's group from Concord](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/When_Freedom_Calls), and meet up with them in Sanctuary. This will give you several farmers immediately. You can assign anybody but Preston to farm, including Mama Murphy and Sturges.

You'll probably want to re-plant your first few harvests. You want at least three of each crop type, and probably six or more.

You'll want to manually harvest each crop whenever you return to Sanctuary. In addition, some crops will be auto-harvested and deposited in your workbench. It's not well understood how this auto-harvesting process works, but I can say from experience that it's okay to leave the crops in your workbench.

Since you will be planting more food than you need, I suggest you store all the melons already at Sanctuary. This reduces the defense you need to cover all your resources, and frees farmers to work on useful crops.

**Purified Water**

You can set up a water purifier in Sanctuary's stream before even leaving Sanctuary to go to Concord, and I recommend you do so. Add additional water purifiers over time, and [sell the excess bottles to increase your income](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/244564/108003).

If you get Science I, you can build an industrial water purifier. This is great, but make sure you have enough defenses to cover all the resources you are producing.

**Making the Starch**

Now that you have all the components, you need a cooking station. There is already one built in Sanctuary, near the main bridge into town. Note that you can move this thing, even if you can't build one. I usually move it closer to the other workstations in the center of town, and plant my crops in the large grassy area there (near where the melons are by default).

When you make Vegetable Starch at the cooking station, it is put in your inventory. You'll want to store it in the workbench before leaving town.

After a while, you'll be producing more adhesive than you can use. This is okay. Making the adhesive gives you experience, and you can sell the excess, or just use it to craft things you don't need for more experience.

Answer (score -1):

There's also the shipment glitch to get loads of resources from any shipment you have. You have to empty all of your junk from your inventory and from your stash into another container. Then go to transfer at your workbench with only the shipments as junk in your inventory. Might wanna save before hand. Then you just hit store all and take all right after. If done correctly you will have the resources in your workbench and still have the shipments in your inventory. Just do it over and over for as much as you want.

Answer (score -4):

If you feel like it there is currently a glitch in trading ammunition that can allow you to acquire a lot of resources for free.

Go to a vendor and select trade.

Select an ammo type (choose the most expensive ammo they sell).

Purchase all that they have.

Sell one (1) unit back.

Sell all the remaining units.

At this point there should be a line of text on your half of the trade that says " .308 Round ". There should be no number value beside it.

Spam that item to add value to your side of the trade until it matches the cost of the vendor's items or cap limit. This enables you to buy anything for free effectively.

Answer (score -6):

there's a ring of tape in the ration supply that doesn't disappear when you grab it so u can just grab it over and over, everyone's been using it lol

Comment: That's not a super well written answer, but the content could be useful if it's true. What ration supply? Do you have a source for this?