# How do you mark components and what effect does it have?

Tags: fallout-4

Inspired by a statement in the question "[How can I get more adhesive?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/243060/how-can-i-get-more-adhesive)":

> I keep adhesive marked as a needed component all the time, and grab every piece of marked junk I see.

How do you mark crafting components? And I'm assuming it just "alerts" you when an item has that material, but how/when will I know exactly?

I play on PS4, in case it matters in terms of buttons.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You're also able to do this from within your inventory on the junk tab by selecting the "Component View" option. This also allows you to remove items from the search list:

[image: component view]

Additionally, when you're in Workshop mode and building, if you do not have all of the required component parts to build an item the "Tag for search" option will enable on the bottom menu bar:

[image: tag for search]

This will add the missing items from the item list to the search list and when you hover over an item that scraps into components including the parts on your search list the item name has a magnifying glass next to it.

[image]

Comment: Also worth noting: when you look at items in your inventory, and it shows the components it breaks down into, the ones you have marked have a magnifying glass next to them. This is useful in stores. I scroll to the item, then glance at the middle to see exactly which components it has that I need, and how many.

Comment: Ah! The fact that you can do it individually in the pip boy makes it so much better.

Answer (score 5):

If you have the "Scrapper" perk at level 2, items that contain tagged components will be highlighted in the world, not just in item lists (e.g. inventory and shops). If such an item is inside a container, the whole container will be highlighted.

However, this only applies to junk, not scrappable items such as weapons and armor.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few ways to tag items for search, but the easiest is to go into your junk inventory and enter component view, you can mark anything you have for search here. If you want to find something you don't have, say for a weapon mod, you can hit the button (it will tell you on-screen) and it will tag all items required for building for search. To do this you have to be at a workbench and highlighting a mod you want to build, items you don't have will be greyed out.

Now once you've tagged an item, you will see a magnifying glass icon next to the name of any junk items that can be broken down into that item. If you were to tag adhesive, junk items like wonderglue and duct tape would have the magnifying glass next to their name. It will appear at all times, whether it's sitting out in the open or in the inventory of something like a toolbox or enemy.