# Where can I find Copper?

Tags: fallout-4

So it seems that most of the electrical items I need to craft require copper resources, which means that I'm going through a lot of copper and it's quickly becoming a very important resource.

I'm currently on the second settlement quest, and I have a quest to build a recruitment antennae however I don't have enough copper.

What items should I be looking out for and are there reliable places to 'farm' copper, or find larger quantities?

Comment: related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/243122/108003

Comment: Your best bet is to find an electronic shop. I can't remember the name of it but I found one early on with plenty of telephones and fuses. Also guarded by robots who dropped relay coils and more fuses. Hot plates you can find in a few places. Most buildings have kitchens where you can find a few there.

Comment: Also worth noting, but not quite answer material, the final level of the scrapper perk will give you more and rarer resources from scrapping weapons, which can sometimes include copper (but mostly is more springs, gears, circuitry and such)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are a few sites (like [this one](http://www.vgamerz.com/fallout-4-guide-how-to-get-all-building-materials/)) that have lists of source materials for copper. I basically pick up everything I can and take it back to my workshop for scrapping. Most of the items that contain copper seem to be electrical items, like lamps/fuses, hot plates, etc. I keep an eye out for those items while I'm scavenging.

Regarding the "large quantities" part, I think that's the challenge. I've been roaming for quite a while, so I've picked up quite a few toasters and hot plates/etc, but they never have tons of copper. It's just a constant struggle to keep an eye out for it.

For reference, I'll repost them here.

**Acid** – Abraxo Cleaner; Anti Freeze Bottle; Suprathaw Antifreeze;

**Adhesive** – Duct Tape; Sealed Wonderglue; Vegetable Starch;

**Aluminum** – Coolant Cap; Distress Pulser;

**Antiseptic** – Abraxo Cleaner; Turpentine; Abraxo Cleaner;

**Asbestos** – Biometric Scanner; Coffee Pot; Extinguisher; Oven Mitt; Pack of Cigarettes; Teapot;

**Bones** – All Bones (ex: Tibia); Animal Parts and Corpses

**Broken Light Bulb** – Street Lamp;

**Ceramics** – Bathtub; Toilet; Ceramic Bowl; Coffee Cup; Sink; Teapot; White Plate;

**Circuitry** – Alarm Clock; Distress Pulser; Enchanted Targeting Card; Military-Grade Circuit Board; Telephone; Hot Plate;

**Cloth** – All Dresses, Suits and Outfits (ex: Laundered Green Dress); All Hood and Hats (ex: Hood with Straps); Box of San Francisco Sunlights; Cigar Box; Couch; Kitchen Chairs; Pre-War Money; Last Edition Newspaper; Pack of Cigarettes, Paintbrush; Rug; Trifold American Flag;

**Cork** – Antique Globe;

**Copper** – Fuse; Hot Plate; Light Bulb; Power Relay Coil; Telephone; Vacuum Tube;

**Crystal** – Camera; Microscope; ProSnap Camera;

**Fiberglass** – Abraxo Cleaner; Cigar Box; Jangles the Moon Monkey; Telephone;

**Fiber Optics** – Biometric Scanner; Microscope;

**Fuse** – Street Lamp;

**Gears** – Adjustable Wrench; Camera; Desk Fan; Gold Watch; Microscope; ProSnap Camera; Typewriter; Silver Pocket Watch;

**Glass** – Beer Bottle; Empty Milk Bottle; Fuse; Glass Pitcher; Lamp; Light Bulb; Nuka Cola Bottle; Shot Glass; Vacuum Tube;

**Gold** – Gold Items (ex: Gold Watch, Gold Lighter);

**Leather** – All Hides and Leathers (ex: Radstag Hide); Some Arm and Leg Pieces (ex: Leather Left Leg); Gas Masks; Harness

**Nuclear Materials** – Alarm Clock; Biometric Scanner; Distress Pulser; Nuclear Material;

**Oil** – Blue Paint; Flip Lighter; Gas Canister; Oil Can; Soap;

**Plastic** – Automatic Institute Pistol; Bread Box; Enchanted Targeting Card; Files; Plastic Spoon; Pack of Cigarettes; Shopping Basket; Scissors; Anti Freeze Bottle;

**Rubber** – Baby Bottle; Fridge; Street Lamp; Tire; Extinguisher;

**Screw** – Antique Globe; Desk Fan; Hot Plate; Typewriter; Toy Car; Toy Truck; Antique Globe;

**Silver** – Silver Items (ex: Silver Fork; Silver Locket; Silver Bowl); Enchanted Targeting Card;

**Spring** – Spring; Camera; Flip Lighter; Kitchen Scale; ProSnap Camera; Typewriter;

**Steel** – All Pistols and Rifles (ex: Pipe Auto Pistol); Ball-peen Hammer; All Melee Weapons (ex: Tire Iron); Some Armor Pieces (ex: Raider Left Arm); Blue Paint; Extinguisher; Flip Lighter; Gas Canister; Kitchen Scale; Mailbox; Oil Can; Radiator; Safe; Shopping Basket; Screwdriver; Scissors; Stove; Street Lamp; Toy Truck; Turpentine;

**Wood** – All Trees (ex: Maple Tree); Wooden Objects (ex: Table); Ball-peen Hammer; Box of San Francisco Sunlights; Cigar Box; Paintbrush; Picture Frame; Screwdriver; Trifold American Flag

Comment: I'm also yet to find a merchant who will sell a bulk order of copper anywhere so far.

Comment: Turns out Arturo the weapon seller in Diamond City does bulk Copper shipments.

Comment: I thought it's worth noting that with the ['Scrapper' perk](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Scrapper_(perk)), you can get Copper from scrapping weapons and armour.

Answer (score 4):

Weapons dealer in Goodneighbor sells bulk copper too.

Answer (score 3):

For bulk copper early in the game, Trudy at Drumlin Diner (near Starlight Drive-in, just south of Concord) sells shipments of 50. Costs a ton of caps, but take along all your chems for trade, or load yourself and your companion down with scavenged gear. Otherwise, grab every electronic piece you see.

Answer (score 0):

It's worth noting that there is a lot of stuff in the institute that can be looted for copper as well as aluminum btw there is a second not so direct route to the FEV lab