# How do I tag components for search without running out of them?

Tags: fallout-4

I'm quite busy with the crafting element of Fallout 4 and I want to pre-emptively start searching for components. When I'm in building mode and trying to place an item that I lack the required components for, I can press <kbd>Q</kbd> (PC) to tag these for search.

However (for example), I also want to tag Glue and Aluminium for search. I do not lack these components right now, but I might once I start using them.

**Can I tag these for search (so they get highlighted in the world) without having run out of them?**

Comment: [The accepted answer to this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/243122/how-do-you-mark-components-and-what-effect-does-it-have) answer that a bit.

Comment: However, @DangerZone, the two questions ask different things, and we dont accept answers as Adequate reason to close as dupe.

Comment: Fair enough @Timelord64.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should put all your junk in your inventory then enter the junk section in your pipboy. Your can press C (PC) to switch into component view. From there you can tag or un-tag any material you have for search.
This might also work without loading the junk in your inventory first, directly from the workbench inventory, but I am not sure right now.

Comment: Can't do it from the workbench. Tried. Wish you could.