# How do I find more resources?

Tags: fallout-4

I have built some settlements but I need help. I can not find supplies that I need. I know that you can break stuff down and all that other good stuff. I'm specifically looking for copper and aluminum. Where and how can I find more of these?

Comment: What sort of supplies are you looking for?

Comment: Copper and aluminum.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are able to mark specific resources in your Pip-Boy so that when you encounter Junk that will break down into those resources, they will be marked with a magnifying glass icon. (See [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/243122/how-do-you-mark-components-and-what-effect-does-it-have))

---

However, since you said you are looking specifically for Copper and Aluminum, here is a list of all the sources of each of them:

[Copper](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Copper):

- Beaker Stand
- Blue Table Lamp
- Bone Cutter
- Broken Lamp
- Broken Light Bulb
- Bunsen Burner
- Condenser Power Module
- Cooking Pot
- Copper Bar
- Fuse
- Gilded Grasshopper
- High-powered Magnet
- Hot Plate
- Light Bulb
- Magnifying Glass
- Power Relay Coil
- Pre-war Lamp
- Shadeless Lamp
- Stew Pot
- Telephone
- Vacuum Tube
- Yellow Table Lamp

As well as shipments of Copper.

[Aluminum](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Aluminum):

- Alarm Clock
- Aluminum Can
- Aluminum Canister
- Applicator
- Cake Pan
- Carlisle Typewriter
- Cauterizer
- Coolant Cap
- Ear Examiner
- Hubcap
- Inactive Distress Pulser
- Ring Stand
- Sensor
- Spanner
- Surgical Tray
- Sweeper
- Toy Rocketship
- Tray
- Tri-tool
- TV Dinner Tray
- Tweezers
- Wakemaster Alarm Clock

And of course, you can buy shipments of Aluminum.

Comment: Corvega Assembly Plant in particular has a bunch of hubcaps and coolant caps you can scrap for aluminum

Comment: Mahkra Fishpacking has a bunch of aluminum trays.

Comment: @Robert__garnet I'm not sure how far you are in the game, but once you get to a *certain Institution*, you'll have aluminum for days.

Comment: not far only level 24