# What's the fastest way to earn money/caps?

Tags: fallout-4

Melon farming? Selling items with a few perks turned on? (Or is that slow because you can only get what shopkeepers have in their cash box?) Rob a bank? What's the most efficacious method for getting rich fast?

Answer (score 17):

The best way I've found to earn caps is to become a moisture farmer.

Every unit of purified water sells for 7+ caps (more if you have the right perks), and its possible to ramp up your water production to the point you are making over 500 units of water per 24 hours.

The best part about it is that the starting town, Sanctuary, is the perfect spot for it, there is a nice and long section of water you can easily fill with multiple water purifiers.

The only thing left to do is to gather these rather common ingredients:

**Industrial Water Purifier:**

- 4 Oil
- 2 Ceramic
- 10 Rubber
- 4 Copper
- 20 Steel
- 4 Cloth
- 6 Screw

**Medium Generator:**

- 3 Screw
- 3 Gear
- 7 Steel
- 3 Rubber
- 3 Copper
- 1 Ceramic

After that, its just a matter of avoiding this glitch[:](https://www.reddit.com/r/falloutsettlements/comments/3tc6fi/no_resources_getting_dropped_off_to_workshop_no/)

> There is currently a glitch in Fallout 4 where the production stops if there are already units of that item in your workshop, so you need to go back to town every once in a while to take out all the purified water and put it into another container.

Here is my Sanctuary water production facility:

[image: My Sanctuary Water Production Facility]

Don't forget to add defense to your town too, it takes 5 heavy machinegun turrets to match the production of 1 industrial purifier, gathering the materials for that is actually more annoying.

Also, if you set up some traders in your town you can carry your water over, dump it all for their inventory of ammo and gear without having to go to diamond city.

Finally, for a second and more easily defensible water production facility, Kingsport Lighthouse is a good choice.

Comment: That's a great screenshot. You don't have issues with the purifiers being attacked? Do you have any defenses set up in the water?

Comment: @Sean nope, I haven't had issues yet, but then I have more defense than water production so it rarely gets attacked.  Also the only entrance to my town is the bridge and that's where I place all my turrets.

Comment: Moisture Farmer?  Luke should have stayed on the farm!

Comment: Nice thing about trading water for ammo: Ammo has no weight. Even missiles and mini-nukes. If it's in the Ammo category, it's weightless. You can use it as an intermediary currency of sorts.

Comment: to be able to sell don't you need charisma Level 6 and local trader perk? or are you saying to take the purified water and carry it to a vendor outside the Sanctuary to sell?

Comment: @kurasa You have a few options, you can always dump it on trashcan carla whenever she appears, trade it with your own traders if you have the perks to set up the trading stands (you need a rank in cap collector too), or you can carry some/all it out (if you have the strong back #4 perk you can fast travel while encumbered).

Comment: @z thanks. I currently have 3 industrial size water purifiers but my water level never seems to change from 29 but I haven't worked out how do i get the water so that I can take it to a trader/vendor onceit is produced. I went to the Environment screen but I can't see any place to 'claim it'

Comment: @kurasa read the bit in my post about the glitch.  it'll explain why your water is stuck at 29

Comment: @z' yes that's the bit I cant get - how do i "take out all the purified water and put it into another container." - where/what menu do I use for this?

Comment: @kurasa interact with any workbench in your settlement (don't craft, use the transfer button), then tab over to AID and grab all the purified water out of it and put it in a separate container that's not linked to the crafting stations.

Comment: It's worth noting that sometimes you can get higher total production by using the slightly smaller water producer as you can more easily place them. Not much of an issue in Sanctuary, but for some of the smaller settlements it can be worth considering.

Answer (score 10):

Crafting the common chems (e.g. Jet and Buffout) and selling them is an easy way to get loads of money fairly quickly. The resources required for Jet are Fertilizer and Plastic, which, while disgusting to picture in your head, are easy to get or cheap to buy.

Next, you sell your Jet stash to the vendor of your choice and get all his caps. If you still have Jet left, travel to the next vendor. Repeat this ad nauseam. If you don't want to travel after exhausting a vendors cash, you can also 1) build your own vendor town in one of your settlements with a load of vendors packed in one spot or 2) trade your Jet for his ammo. Either you need it to kill stuff or you can trade it for something else later, which is convenient since ammo has no weight.

Comment: Is it worth more to craft combo chems like buffjet, or to sell them individually?

Comment: I'd say sell them individually. They bring in some 5 caps for combining them but also require other materials that could themselves be sold. It is also less time-consuming if you don't have to look for those components.

Comment: I've been making Jet quite a bit. It's not profitable if you have low charisma and no perks, but with Cap Collector 2 and decent charisma it's just like you say. The vendors don't have enough caps to buy all the drugs I'm pushing. But even if it's not profitable, you get nice XP. I often finish a level pumping out Jet. Don't forget to wear your Int gear while crafting it.