# Why are my food resources unable to be assigned in Fallout 4?

Tags: fallout-4

I'm playing Fallout 4 on the PC and ran across a problem. A quick Google didn't help. One of my homesteads got attacked. I was there so it wasn't a problem to demolish even without defenses. Then I harvested some of the plants and when I came back they hadn't regrown. Realizing there was no one assigned to them, I grabbed a new settler at the farm and told him to farm it.

The game informed me it was assigned, but looking away and checking the little person that tells you if it's assigned said it still wasn't. One of the plants also won't be repaired.

I gave up for a while, ended up stopping gameplay and doing other stuff for several hours. Then when I loaded up the game, and had a quest to go back to the same farm, the issue was worse. Now I couldn't even select the previously unassignable tatos.

I tried a fix that had you move a working tato plant on top of the nonworking one and then load a save, that resulted in the nonworking one working but the formerly working one now being nonfunctional. And the tatos still wouldn't assign anyway.

I have better food places, I don't even need this farm that much for Tatos, but fixing the bug would be nice. If anyone has a quick fix I'd appreciate it.

Comment: When you hover over the person you assigned to the plant in workshop view, does it highlight the plant, or anything else?

Comment: @DCShannon it doesn't highlight anything except the person in question.

Comment: Just to doublecheck, you can't store the tato plant?

Comment: @DCShannon I could. Made it register as food again too, which was nice.

The busted one that won't repair is still borked though.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience if you plant something near the bugged plant, assign a settler to that plant, and let the farming run its course, these issues tend to resolve themselves over time.

I've had invasions occur ON my farm plots, and have watched my missile turrets decimate the farm plots, and then not be able to select the destroyed crops.. Poor farm/defense layout aside, this is the circumstance in which I came back later and notice that the plants were eventually revived.

In short, I wouldn't worry so much about micro-managing the efficiency of every single plant. If food and water is sufficient for stability or growth, that's good enough for me!

Comment: Beside stability and growth, plants can be grown for materials to be used in recipes. Especially [Vegetable Starch](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/243062/108003). So, having one Tato not produce can be a bit annoying, even if everybody has enough food.

Answer (score -3):

For anyone unsure whats happening. Watch this video:

I did and I now know what is happening and how to get them back selectable again.

Comment: Could you summarise what's happening in the video? If it gets taken down it's good to have a record of what it was.